# Issue on Setting Two Pet Horizontal Line

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/163bfqf6/) and let me know how to style the `<hr>` to look like following image:

[image]

I tried this:

```
hr {
    border-top: 3px solid red; 
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue; 
}
```

but it seems I need to use `::after Pseudo-element`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `:before` :pseudo element:

```css
hr:before {
    content: "";
    width: 40px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #F8CC05;
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    left: -1px;
}
hr {
    position: relative;
    color: #DDDDDD;
}
```

```html
<hr />
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
hr:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 5px;
      left: 8px;
      border-bottom: 4px solid #F7C51E;
      width: 40px;
}
```